# Produce separate line plots with multiple legend items

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have generated the following DataFrame (a small subset shown here) and wish to generate a separate line plot for each zone, with each plot having multiple legend items ('green', 'red' and 'brown' from the Cat column). The x-axis will use 'Date' and the y-axis 'Val'.

I am relatively new to Python/Pandas and have been trying to solve this problem for several days, without success. Does anyone have any ideas on how to iterate through the zones and group the values from the Cat column? A number of people have posted similar questions about this, but they didn't need to generate separate plots for a column (e.g. Zone) before grouping values from a second column.

```
Zone  Cat    Date     Val
A    green  198711    44
A    red    198711    47
A    brown  198711    40
A    green  198808    52
A    red    198808    53
A    brown  198808    49
A    green  199002    57
A    red    199002    59
A    brown  199002    53
B    red    198711    46
B    green  198711    43
B    brown  198711    45
B    red    198808    48
B    green  198808    48
B    brown  198808    51
B    red    199002    50
B    green  199002    49
B    brown  199002    51
```

Comment: are you looking for 3 separate bar charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **seaborn**.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.factorplot(x="Date", y="Val", hue="Cat", col="Zone", data=df)
```

[image: output plot]

Update 'to save a series of individual factorplots':

```
for zone in df.Zone.unique():
    fig = sns.factorplot(x="Date", y="Val", hue="Cat", col="Zone", data=df[df.Zone==zone])
    fig.savefig("zone_{0}.png".format(zone))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job with minimal code. It would be interesting to see if the code could be expanded to save a series of individual factorplots.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `Cat` column.

```
df.groupby('Cat`).plot(x='Date', y='Val')
```

I'm not quite sure what kind of plot you are wanting, but this is the idea.

---

Update:

I think I understand better now. You want different plots for zones and different graphs on those plots for categories

You can just iterate through the `Zone`'s and then use the `groupby` like above

```
for zone in set(df['Zone']):
    df[df['Zone']==zone].groupby('Cat`).plot(x='Date', y='Val')
```

Comment: I misused the term 'plot', sorry. To clarify, I would like to generate separate graph for each zone, with each graph having three line plots ('red', 'green' and 'brown') from Cat.

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure which word means which... :P

Comment: I think you want 3 squares [  ] with each have a line for each Cat? I think that's what the second code I gave does...

Comment: No, I'm looking for the type of output that Lambda demonstrated using Seaborn factorplot. Factorplot would be fine for a handful of zones, but my dataset has over 100. I'm trying to find a way to output each graph - once I can get the basic code to produce the graphs.